# HDD does not work from lying in a drawer

Tags: hard-drive

Please let me know if anyone has met with such a situation, that fit the hard drive HDD after a period of lying in the closet (without electricity) broke down - ie. He stopped working permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Never. Electronic components of any kind could not be broken just by being stored.
Probably something more happened. There are electronics subcomponents that **can** be destroyed in process of removing components from work to storage, from something called electrostatic discharge. For more info please check:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge

That's one possible root of problem, second would be mishandling (drops from height over 1 meters), which is not present here if you yourself disconnected the drive.

Third, capacitors on old equipment (not SMD, but grain-sized electrolytic capacitors) in time stop working.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolytic_capacitor

I know a guy who repairs old Macs just by replacing electrolytic capacitors, as everything else is (usually) working fine, and THAT is weak point.

*Disclaimer:* Please have in mind that capacitors are most probably not the cause of your problem, I wrote this just to give a complete answer of possible causes of electronic equipment malfunction due to storage.

Comment: I was the second such case that fit the hard drive after lying about half a year in a drawer would not work when connected - rule out shocks etc.